# How I can get user location (longitude and latitude) in node.js and express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I want use user location to tell there weather report from openweathermap API but I can't figure it out that how I can get the location. please help me

I tried using this but this didn't work can anyone explain me why and what are the solutions I searched this on internet but there answers are to use another api to get location through IP address
but that is not accurate so can anyone tell me the solution of this ? and there is nothing coming in console
btw I am new so if there is a mistake please tell me

and there is nothing coming in console

});

```
app.post("/weather", async (req,res) =>{
    try{
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              const lat = position.coords.latitude;
              const lon = position.coords.longitude;
              console.log(`Latitude: ${lat}, Longitude: ${lon}`);
            });
          } else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
          };

        

    const result = await axios.post(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${weatherapi}`);
    const result1= JSON.stringify(result.data);
    res.render("weather.ejs",{content: result1});
    
    }catch (error) {
        res.render("weather.ejs", { content: JSON.stringify(error.response) });
      }

});
```

Comment: `navigator.geolocation` exists on the client side, whereas you appear to be trying to use it in server-side code here.

Comment: You can't get it on the server-side. You have to get it in the browser and then send it to the server

Comment: @Konrad can you tell me how to do that please ?